# Could not resolve pointer: /definitions/Error-ModelName

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, springfox

I am new to Swagger.io and so also to Spring fox. The problem I am having is, that for some Reason one Object is not correctly referenced to its model.

The error in the UI:
[image]

The error is because it ends up like this in the JSON:

```
"schema": {
"$ref": "#/definitions/Error-ModelName{namespace='online.staffmanager.backend.auth.model.dto', name='UserChangeSet'}"
}
```

if I change it to:

```
"schema": {
"$ref": "#/definitions/UserChangeSet"
}
```

it does work. And I have no Idea why the anotations are mapping it like this.

My Annotations:

```
 @Operation(
            tags = "auth",
            summary = "Create a new User Account",
            responses = {
                    @ApiResponse(
                            responseCode = "200",
                            content = @Content(schema = @Schema(implementation = TokenInfo.class))),
                    @ApiResponse(
                            responseCode = "201",
                            content = @Content(schema = @Schema(implementation = UserChangeSet.class)))
            }
    )
```

SpringFoxConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
@EnableWebMvc
public class SpringFoxConfig {

    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build();
    }

}
```

Note: I am using Springfox 3.0.0.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem. Created an issue to track the it - https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/3646

Comment: @meshuga Thank you, I am curious about the result.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you have to add one more configuration to the Bean.

Here is the configuration need to be added:

```
.additionalModels(
     typeResolver.resolve(TokenInfo.class),
     typeResolver.resolve(UserChangeSet.class)
 )
```

This is full code:

```
@Configuration
@Import(SpringDataRestConfiguration.class)
public class SwaggerUIConfig {

    @Bean
    public Docket api(TypeResolver typeResolver) {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .additionalModels(
                    typeResolver.resolve(TokenInfo.class),
                    typeResolver.resolve(UserChangeSet.class)
             )
            .select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.projectname.controllers"))
            .paths(PathSelectors.any())
            .build()
            .useDefaultResponseMessages(false);

     }
}
```

**Note**: @EnableSwagger2 annotation is recommended to remove in version 3.0. You can refer http://springfox.github.io/springfox/docs/current/#migrating-from-existing-2-x-version

I hope can help you.

Answer (score 0):

In my case using Generic types got solution:

```
 @PutMapping(path = "/home")
 public ResponseEntity<Void>(....)
```

TO

```
 @PutMapping(path = "/home")
 public ResponseEntity (....)
```